# Adding files to all users 'My Documents' folders in Windows

Tags: windows, installation, directory, inno-setup

I am creating an installer (using Inno Setup) for a windows application. The app has initial documents that I need to store in the users 'My Documents' folder.

Here is the issue, I install it as an Admin, but there may be one or many non admin users on that machine. How can i add that same folder to all the possible current (and future user's) My Documents folder?

Here is what i have tried so far-

1) I could try to pick up all usernames - This however, wont work for future user creations :(

2) I have tried to add it to the systems %allusersprofile%\Documents folder. It does not get reflected to individual My Documents folders.

I believe there should be a way, but have been unable to find a clean solution off the internet till now. Can anyone direct me towards the right path?

Mucho Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a construct for this in Windows. You have a few options:

1. Put the document in some common place (like `%allusersprofile%\Documents`, or `%program files%\yourCompany\yourApp\documents`) and create a start menu link/icon that points to either the folder with the documents or the document itself.
2. Put the document into the Default User documents folder. When a new user is created, their profile is setup to mirror that of the default user. This doesn't help you with current users, but it does help you for users who haven't been created (logged on)

I'd go with option 1 because it's relatively standard and its what your average user is going to expect.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Inno Setup [Shell Folder Constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) : `{commondocs}`